# How do I make sure that a shiny reactive plot only changes once all other reactives finish changing?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app in which the user selects a bunch of inputs, such as the x range, y range, types of scaling and the selection of a particular subset of the data set through a drop down list.

This is all done through the use of reactives. X and Y range slider inputs react to changes in the selection of the data set because the minimum and maximum have to be found again. This takes maybe about 1-2 seconds while the shiny app is working and the user chooses a different option in the drop down list. During those 1-2 seconds, the plot switches to plotting the selected new subset of data with the old x and y range before quickly switching to the correct plot once the x and y range sliders change.

A fix would be to just refresh the plot on a button by isolating everything else. But would there be a way to keep the plot reactive to changes, but just wait until all the dependent things have finished calculating?

Thanks

This is the plot:

```
output$plot1 <- rCharts::renderChart2({    
    if(!is.null(input$date_of_interest) && 
         !is.null(input$xrange) && 
         !is.null(input$yrange) &&
         !is.null(data()) &&
         isolate(valid_date_of_interest())) {
      filtered_data<- dplyr::filter(isolate(data()), id==input$choice)
      p <- tryCatch(plot_high_chart(
                           data,
                           first_date_of_interest = input$date_of_interest, 
                           ylim = input$yrange,
                           xlim = input$xrange), 
                    error = function(e) e, 
                    warning = function(w) w)
      if(!inherits(p, "error") && !inherits(p, "warning")) {
        return(p)
      }
    } 
    return(rCharts::Highcharts$new())
  })
```

and x range(y range is similar):

```
output$xrange <- renderUI({
    if(!is.null(input$date_of_interest) && 
       !is.null(input$choice) &&
       !is.null(valid_date_of_interest()) &&
       isolate(valid_date_of_interest())) {
          temp_data <- dplyr::filter(isolate(data()), date == input$date_of_interest)
          temp <- data.table::data.table(temp_data, key = "child.id")
          the_days <- as.double(as.Date(temp$last.tradeable.dt) - as.Date(temp$date))
          min_days <- min(the_days,na.rm=TRUE)
          max_days <- max(the_days,na.rm=TRUE)
          sliderInput("xrange", 
                      "Days Range (X Axis)", 
                       step = 1,
                       min = 0,
                       max = max_days + 10,
                       value = c(min_days,max_days)
      )
    }
  })
```

and the input choice:

```
 output$choice<- renderUI({
    selectInput("choice", 
                "Choose:", 
                unique(data$id),
                selected = 1    
    )
  })
```

Some direction and suggestions to implement would be useful. I've thought about having global variables such as x_range_updated, y_range_updated, that are set to false in the code for output$choice and then set to true in the code for output$xrange, etc. And then have plot1 depend on them being true. Other suggestions to approach this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: `runApp(.., display.mode = "showcase")` will highlight a code running. Probably it could help you to understand

Comment: Hey Andriy, I understand what the program is doing, I'm just not sure how to change the behavior such that it eliminates refreshing the plot twice.

Comment: OK. I think you could add a `submit button` so then the changes in selectors wouldn't provoke reaction on your plot before yo press a sumbit button

Comment: Hey Andriy, yeah that will definitely work, but I was trying to see if there was a way to avoid having to have a button.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Edit 2019-02-14

Since Shiny 1.0.0 (released after I originally wrote this answer), there is now a `debounce` function which adds functionality to help with this kind of task. For the most part, this avoids the need for the code I originally wrote, although under the hood it works in a similar manner. However, as far as I can tell, `debounce` doesn't offer any way of short-circuiting the delay with a redraw action button along the lines of what I'd done here. I've therefore created a modified version of `debounce` that offers this functionality:

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)

# Redefined in global namespace since it's not exported from shiny
`%OR%` <- shiny:::`%OR%`
debounce_sc <- function(r, millis, priority = 100, domain = getDefaultReactiveDomain(), short_circuit = NULL) 
{
  force(r)
  force(millis)
  if (!is.function(millis)) {
    origMillis <- millis
    millis <- function() origMillis
  }
  v <- reactiveValues(trigger = NULL, when = NULL)
  firstRun <- TRUE
  observe({
    r()
    if (firstRun) {
      firstRun <<- FALSE
      return()
    }
    v$when <- Sys.time() + millis()/1000
  }, label = "debounce tracker", domain = domain, priority = priority)
  # New code here to short circuit the timer when the short_circuit reactive
  # triggers
  if (inherits(short_circuit, "reactive")) {
    observe({
      short_circuit()
      v$when <- Sys.time()
    }, label = "debounce short circuit", domain = domain, priority = priority)
  }
  # New code ends
  observe({
    if (is.null(v$when)) 
      return()
    now <- Sys.time()
    if (now >= v$when) {
      v$trigger <- isolate(v$trigger %OR% 0) %% 999999999 + 
        1
      v$when <- NULL
    }
    else {
      invalidateLater((v$when - now) * 1000)
    }
  }, label = "debounce timer", domain = domain, priority = priority)
  er <- eventReactive(v$trigger, {
    r()
  }, label = "debounce result", ignoreNULL = FALSE, domain = domain)
  primer <- observe({
    primer$destroy()
    er()
  }, label = "debounce primer", domain = domain, priority = priority)
  er
}
```

This then permits a simplified shiny application. I've switched to the single file mode of working, but the UI remains the same as the original one.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30),
      selectInput("column", "Column", colnames(faithful), selected = "waiting"),
      actionButton("redraw", "Redraw")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  reac <- reactive(list(bins = input$bins, column  = input$column)) %>% 
    debounce_sc(5000, short_circuit = reactive(input$redraw))

  # Only triggered by the debounced reactive
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, reac()$column]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = reac()$bins + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
         main = sprintf("Histogram of %s", reac()$column))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### Original version (pre Shiny 1.0.0)

You haven't provided a reproducible example, so I've gone with something based on the Shiny faithful example that is the default in RStudio. The solution I've got will always have a (configurable) 5 second delay between an input changing and the graph being redrawn. Each change in input resets the timer. There's also a redraw button for the impatient which redraws the graph immediately. The values of the reactive value 'redraw' and the inputs are shown in the console every time an input changes or the timer ticks. This should be removed for production use. Hopefully this meets your needs!

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30),
      selectInput("column", "Column", colnames(faithful), selected = "waiting"),
      actionButton("redraw", "Redraw")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))
```

### server.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  reac <- reactiveValues(redraw = TRUE, bins = isolate(input$bins), column  = isolate(input$column))

  # If any inputs are changed, set the redraw parameter to FALSE
  observe({
    input$bins
    input$column
    reac$redraw <- FALSE
  })

  # This event will also fire for any inputs, but will also fire for
  # a timer and with the 'redraw now' button.
  # The net effect is that when an input is changed, a 5 second timer
  # is started. This will be reset any time that a further input is
  # changed. If it is allowed to lapse (or if the button is pressed)
  # then the inputs are copied into the reactiveValues which in turn
  # trigger the plot to be redrawn.
  observe({
    invalidateLater(5000, session)
    input$bins
    input$column
    input$redraw
    isolate(cat(reac$redraw, input$bins, input$column, "\n"))
    if (isolate(reac$redraw)) {
      reac$bins <- input$bins
      reac$column <- input$column
    } else {
      isolate(reac$redraw <- TRUE)
    }
  })

  # Only triggered when the copies of the inputs in reac are updated
  # by the code above
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      x    <- faithful[, reac$column]
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = reac$bins + 1)
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
           main = sprintf("Histogram of %s", reac$column))
  })
})
```

Comment: Nice solution Nick, which also teaches a good lesson about reactive values generally. Just found that a shiny function (validate) is available now which does the job:

http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/validate.html

Comment: @ChriiSchee Thanks for the feedback. I've just looked at validate, and it looks as though this offers something different - it allows the programmer to check that all of the inputs are valid, but doesn't allow a delay between updating a value and recalculating the output.

Comment: @NickKennedy Great explanation +1. Given changes to shiny + future/promises, is this still how you would attack this today?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns thanks for the comment. I’ve not made use of promises in Shiny yet, but it looks as though they solve a different problem; they allow the Shiny process to better serve multiple users, but in the example given here they wouldn’t avoid the issue of redundant calculations when the user changes two inputs in quick succession.

Comment: Thanks @NickKennedy -- seems like a lot of work/upkeep just for a delay. I run into this problem with reactive data.frame objects (filtered from sliders) driving (multiple) plot outputs. This works, but it's a lot of added overhead.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns the alternative is to use a redraw button and manually redraw.

Comment: @NickKennedy oh I know...but then I'd be assuming my customers can actually "do work" ;-)

Comment: @JasonAizkalns A modified version of `debounce` would work. See edit above

Comment: @NickKennedy interesting. Would you mind a few more code comments? A bit difficult to understand exactly what's going on here on the first read through. Do you think this is better/worse than the original approach?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns it’s very similar, it’s just most of the code is now a slightly modified version of a function already in shiny. I’m planning to post an issue to shiny on github with suggested code to add this functionality to the package. If this is accepted, then all you’d need would be the server code.

Comment: @NickKennedy running into this myself and trying your solution. I couldn't find your planned shiny issue; did I miss it? https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/created_by/NikNakk

Comment: @NickKennedy Your codes worked very well for me recently. However, when I reinstalled my Rstudio as well as R software, an error has started to occur that I couldn't figure out any specific reason. The issue comes as the function %OR% not found in R even though the shiny and magrittr libraries have already loaded. Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : object '%OR%' not found Thanks