# Shiny: Wait for function till user stops typing

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I have users calling functions while typing. The problem is that it makes the call for every letter being typed and error is shown if textbox is empty even for 1ms.

`Warning: Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall: Forbidden (HTTP 403).`

How can I change this to make the function call only after about 400ms after the last typed letter?

Here is my Shiny code:

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textInput("new_hashtag", label = h4("Enter #Hashtag"), value = "#hello")
        )
    ),
    mainPanel(
        DT::dataTableOutput('mytable1')
    )
))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        df <- searchTwitter(as.character(input$new_hashtag)
        DT::datatable(twListToDF(df))
    })        
})
```

Comment: You have 2 different options: 1) Force user to click a submit button, 2) Update JavaScript to listen for an Enter or pause between keystrokes. The second option is a better user experience, but you'll need some extra knowledge of JavaScript.

Comment: Yes this can be one option, but I am also looking for something in R which can help me in this.

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38960525/5894457). `Debounce` might just be what you are looking for.