# Only update input on close

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

I'd like to have my pickerInput only update on close. Apparently, this is an already-requested [feature](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/issues/392) with a [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68845540/prevent-pickerinput-from-updating-every-time-something-is-selected-r-shiny).

The issue I'm having is integrating that solution with my existing module structure. My current app structure has a module that updates the next picker in a hierarchy when the picker above it is changed.

I tried adding a second condition for my observeEvent in the moduleController as well as adding another observeEvent condition to the server, neither of which worked.

I know I need to use the input$..._open element, but because I'm generating the select inputs via a module I'm struggling to explicitly ID it in the observeEvent.

Is there a way to programmatically list all input ids with a certain phrase or pattern and include the update logic in the `moduleController` and `moduleRootController` functions?

Overall I’d like ALL pickers created by `moduleController` and `moduleRootController` to only update on close.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(highcharter)

# module UI

moduleUI <- function(id, label, choices = NULL) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(virtualSelectInput(ns("select"), label= label, choices = choices,
                             selected = choices, multiple = TRUE))
}

# module server root

moduleRootController <- function(id) {
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    return(reactive({input$select}))
    
  })
}

# module server

moduleController <- function(id, data, selector, input_val, output_val) {
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    observeEvent(selector(), {
      choices=data %>%
        filter({{input_val}} %in% selector()) %>%
        distinct({{output_val}}) %>%
        arrange({{output_val}}) %>%
        pull({{output_val}})
      updateVirtualSelect("select", choices = choices, selected = choices)
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
    
    return(reactive({input$select}))
    
  })
}

ui_heirarchy <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(moduleUI(ns("ModuleRoot"), label = "Root Label", choices=c("A", "B", "C", "D")),
          moduleUI(ns("Module1"), label = "Test Label 1"),
          moduleUI(ns("Module2"), label = "Test Label 2"),
          moduleUI(ns("Module3"), label = "Test Label 3"))
}

server_heirarchy <- function(id, data) {
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    mod0 <- moduleRootController("ModuleRoot")
    mod1 <- moduleController("Module1", data, reactive({mod0()}), level1, level2)
    mod2 <- moduleController("Module2", data, reactive({mod1()}), level2, level3)
    mod3 <- moduleController("Module3", data, reactive({mod2()}), level3, level4)
    
    return(list(mod0 = mod0, mod1 = mod1, mod2 = mod2, mod3 = mod3))
    
  })
}

# ui / server / app

ui <- fixedPage(
  tags$style(type="text/css", ".recalculating {opacity: 0.05;}"),
  ui_heirarchy("heirarchy"),
  highchartOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  x <- tibble(level1 = c(rep("A", 100), rep("B", 100), rep("C", 100), rep("D", 100)),
              level2 = c(rep("A1", 50), rep("A2", 50), rep("B1", 50), rep("B2", 50),
                         rep("C1", 50), rep("C2", 50), rep("D1", 50), rep("D2", 50)),
              level3 = c(rep("A21", 25), rep("A22", 25), rep("A23", 25), rep("A24", 25),
                         rep("B21", 25), rep("B22", 25), rep("B23", 25), rep("B24", 25),
                         rep("C21", 25), rep("C22", 25), rep("C23", 25), rep("C24", 25),
                         rep("D21", 25), rep("D22", 25), rep("D23", 25), rep("D24", 25)),
              level4 = c(rep("A31", 10), rep("A32", 10), rep("A33", 10), rep("A34", 10), rep("A35", 10),
                         rep("A36", 10), rep("A37", 10), rep("A38", 10), rep("A39", 10), rep("A310", 10),
                         rep("B31", 10), rep("B32", 10), rep("B33", 10), rep("B34", 10), rep("B35", 10),
                         rep("B36", 10), rep("B37", 10), rep("B38", 10), rep("B39", 10), rep("B310", 10),
                         rep("C31", 10), rep("C32", 10), rep("C33", 10), rep("C34", 10), rep("C35", 10),
                         rep("C36", 10), rep("C37", 10), rep("C38", 10), rep("C39", 10), rep("C310", 10),
                         rep("D31", 10), rep("D32", 10), rep("D33", 10), rep("D34", 10), rep("D35", 10),
                         rep("D36", 10), rep("D37", 10), rep("D38", 10), rep("D39", 10), rep("D310", 10))) %>%
    mutate(value = runif(400, 0, 100))
  
  out <- server_heirarchy("heirarchy", x)
  
  
  # Do this to make pickers
  y <- reactive({
    
    req(out$mod3())
    
    x %>%
      filter(level1 %in% out$mod0()) %>%
      filter(level2 %in% out$mod1()) %>%
      filter(level3 %in% out$mod2()) %>%
      filter(level4 %in% out$mod3())
    
  })
  
  debounced_y <- debounce(y, 1000)
  
  # Then query picker output
  
  query <- reactive({
    req(debounced_y())
    Sys.sleep(5) #mimics query time
    debounced_y()
  })
  
  # Then plot query
  
  output$plot <- renderHighchart({
    hc <- hchart(
      query()$value, 
      color = "#B71C1C", name = "Weight"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shinywidgets [now has an option](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/issues/677#issuecomment-2010163521) for update on close for virtualSelectInput.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for this.

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

x <- tibble(level1 = c(rep("A", 100), rep("B", 100), rep("C", 100), rep("D", 100)),
            level2 = c(rep("A1", 50), rep("A2", 50), rep("B1", 50), rep("B2", 50),
                       rep("C1", 50), rep("C2", 50), rep("D1", 50), rep("D2", 50)),
            level3 = c(rep("A21", 25), rep("A22", 25), rep("A23", 25), rep("A24", 25),
                       rep("B21", 25), rep("B22", 25), rep("B23", 25), rep("B24", 25),
                       rep("C21", 25), rep("C22", 25), rep("C23", 25), rep("C24", 25),
                       rep("D21", 25), rep("D22", 25), rep("D23", 25), rep("D24", 25)),
            level4 = c(rep("A31", 10), rep("A32", 10), rep("A33", 10), rep("A34", 10), rep("A35", 10),
                       rep("A36", 10), rep("A37", 10), rep("A38", 10), rep("A39", 10), rep("A310", 10),
                       rep("B31", 10), rep("B32", 10), rep("B33", 10), rep("B34", 10), rep("B35", 10),
                       rep("B36", 10), rep("B37", 10), rep("B38", 10), rep("B39", 10), rep("B310", 10),
                       rep("C31", 10), rep("C32", 10), rep("C33", 10), rep("C34", 10), rep("C35", 10),
                       rep("C36", 10), rep("C37", 10), rep("C38", 10), rep("C39", 10), rep("C310", 10),
                       rep("D31", 10), rep("D32", 10), rep("D33", 10), rep("D34", 10), rep("D35", 10),
                       rep("D36", 10), rep("D37", 10), rep("D38", 10), rep("D39", 10), rep("D310", 10)))

# Modules

moduleUI <- function(id, label) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(pickerInput(ns("select"), label= label, choices=c(), multiple = TRUE, options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, `live-search`=TRUE)))
}

moduleController <- function(id, choiceLists, selector, open, parent_session) { 
    moduleServer(
      id,
      function(input, output, session) {
        ns <- session$ns
        
        observeEvent(selector(), {
          choices <- choiceLists %>%
            filter(level1 %in% selector()) %>%
            distinct(level2) %>%
            arrange(level2) %>%
            pull(level2)
          
          if (!isTRUE(open()) & !isTRUE(input$select_open)) { 
            updatePickerInput(session=parent_session, ns("select"), choices=choices, selected = choices)
          }
        })
        
        return(reactive({input$select}))
      })
}

# ui / server / app

ui <- fixedPage(
  pickerInput("module1Mode", label="Set Label", choices=c("A", "B", "C", "D"), selected = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), multiple = TRUE, options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, `live-search`=TRUE)),
  moduleUI("Module1", label = "Test Label"),
  textOutput("mod1Text"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  open <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$module1Mode)) opn <- FALSE
    else opn <- input$module1Mode_open
    opn
  })
  
  mod1 <- reactive({
    open()
    mod <- moduleController("Module1", x, reactive({input$module1Mode}), open, session)
    value <- mod()
    value
  })

  output$mod1Text <- renderText({
    paste("Test Label selection is delayed till module1Mode pickerInput is closed", paste(mod1(), collapse=","))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This looks promising! Is there a way to have the second picker only update on close too? Potentially a more robust solution where if I added a 3rd or 4th picker from the hierarchy they also would only update on close?

Comment: updated question to reflect comment above.